# Intercepting a signal with ESP32/Arduino - resistor placement

Tags: arduino, esp32

I'm hacking a callbell to connect an ESP32 in order to send me a Telegram notification. The software side is OK but I'm having difficulty in detecting when the callbell goes off. When it is triggered, 5 LEDs flash. They are connected in parallel with +5V at the anode and via a 2K resistor into a pin on an unmarked IC.

Ideally, I'd solder a wire between the resistor and the IC to detect the falling edge but there is very little space. Between the LEDs and the resistor there is sufficient space to attach a lead but I can't make it trigger an interrupt. My question is, can I add my own 2K resistor between this lead and the GPIO pin?

[circuit diagrams](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wcC0.jpg)

Edit: managed to solder a lead between the resistor and the IC. Project deployed and works well. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. Just make sure your device has a common GND wit your ESP32. Also measure the voltage there and check the required resistor resistance..

EDIT: If I am right, this will connect GND to the digital pin, that should be pulled HIGH, then you can detect the GND.
Also connecting a transistor to switch 3.3V when gnd is given by the IC can be a good solution.